# Odds of being the last pick in a draw, twice.

Tags: statistics

My brother's work did a draw where they had 27 participants. They would draw a name until 1 remained, who would be the winner. He did a mock draw yesterday and the real draw today and the same person won both times.

What are the odds of winning a draw of this nature once, and twice consecutively? It has been a long time since I did this sort of math and I cannot recall the theory behind these calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be $1/27$.  The first draw has to have a winner.  Each person has the same chance of winning the second draw, so the chance of one specific person (the first time winner) is $1/27$.  That sounds small, but you wouldn't be remarking on it if it were somebody else that won.